# Why does the main function in Java reside in a class?

Tags: java, class

I just started studying Java. And the main function of the program always resides in a class.

```
public class t{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  // do stuff
  }
}
```

I have studied C++, and in there the main function doesn't need to be in a class. Why in Java we have to do that?

Why can't the main function exist in Java without a class, like it does in C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably for the same reason you put question marks at the end of a question: that's just how they decided it's done.

The `main` method is the result of a convention that says "this is how the entry point's method signature should look" which doesn't exempt it from language semantics.

Java does not support methods outside of classes/interfaces and as such it has to be contained in one.

Comment: So, there wasn't any specific reason for including the main function in the class? They could have just allowed a main function without a class and it would have made no difference?

Comment: @ooodddbbb - It makes a lot of difference. The *language was designed that way*. Only when a class is loaded, we will ahve access to its members. So to access `main()` we need to *load* the enclosing class.

Comment: @TheLostMind That made a lot of sense. Also, main is the only member of that class which contains it right? Thanks Anyways

Comment: @ooodddbbb - What do you mean by - *They could have just allowed a main function without a class and it would have made no difference* ? . PS - I really hope *Jeroen* doesn't mind this conversation on his *answer* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind I meant: In C++ we dont have to enclose the main function in a class. Why didn't they do it for JAVA? Does enclosing the main function in a class make any difference at all?

Comment: @ooodddbbb - No. Like this answer clearly states, *The main method is the result of a convention that says "this is how the entry point's method signature should look" which doesn't exempt it from language semantics.*. C++ is not *Java*, the *signatures* and *behavior* are different.

Comment: @TheLostMind I got that.

Comment: @ooodddbbb It makes an *immeasurable* difference. The whole of Java platform is based on the premise of a class as a code module. Classes are what you load to get executable code. They are the .so libraries of Javaspace. Get over it---the sooner the better.

Answer (score 3):

The "every method in Java must be in a class because the spec says so" answer is only part of the story. By having main() inside a class it is possible to have multiple entry points within a project. i.e. multiple classes with main() methods. This allows you to select a different main class at runtime rather than compile time. e.g.

```
java -cp program.jar com.example.Class1
```

or then if you want to run a different main from the same jar

```
java -cp program.jar com.example.Class2
```

Answer (score 1):

1. All methods must reside in a class in Java.
2. `main` is a method.

Therefore, `main` must reside in a class.

Furthermore, a class is not just a blueprint of an object. It is by itself a chunk of code that does something. One of the things it does is providing the entry point of the application by containing a `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because **everything is inside a class** in Java. Java code consists only of classes. They may be nested in themselves or in a packagehierarchy, but nothing is allowed to appear outside of a class.

<sub>The only exceptions are the `package` and `import` statements.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how the language was designed. The JVM first loads the class containing the main function and then calls the `main()` method. Without loading the class, `main()` cannot be called, i.e, `main()` doesn't exist without its *enclosing* class.

Answer (score 0):

since java is oop language , u cant do anything unless u create a class. this makes java object oriented language. and java was designed like that to first to load the public class and call main method

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider that following is allowed in java

```
void main (){
  f1();
  f2();

}
int f1(){
  f2();
  return 1;
}
int f2(){
   return 3;
}
```

since there are no prototypes in java how would main call f1 or f2 or how would f1 call f2?
i Think that this is one of the reasons